# Отменить запрос

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Пролистал официальную [документацию](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-cancel-requests) и решил перенести нечто подобное в свой проект, чтобы у пользователя всегда была возможность отменить загрузку файлов и всё бы работало корректно. Имплементировал необходимые методы, где в failure прописал следующее:

```
service.upload1(file1, str, stringMap, new Callback<ImageUpload>() {
            @Override
            public void success(final ImageUpload imageUpload, Response response) {
                mRecyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ...
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                if (error.isCanceled()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "request is cancelled");
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "other larger issue, i.e. no network connection?");
                }
            }
```

Но выделяет красным **isCanceled** в методе failure. Не совсем понимал сначало в чем проблема, потому как этот метод нам изначально предлагается классом *Call*, но оказывается это для Retrofit 2, а у меня в проекте используется 1.9.

Подскажите пожалуйста как **в данной версии** можно реализовать отмену запроса.

Answer (score 2):

Для отмены запроса попробуйте сделать следующее:

```
public class CancellableCallback<T> implements Callback<T> {

private Callback<T> callback;
private boolean canceled;
private CancellableCallback() {}

public CancellableCallback(Callback<T> callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
    canceled = false;
}

public void cancel() {
    canceled = true;
    callback = null;
}

@Override
public void success(T o, Response response) {
    if (!canceled) {
        callback.success(o, response);
    }
}

@Override
public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
    if (!canceled) {
        callback.failure(error);
    }
}
```

Дальше меняете свой код на нечто похожее:

```
CancellableCallback callback = new Callback<ImageUpload>() {
        @Override
        public void success(final ImageUpload imageUpload, Response response) {
            mRecyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ...
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

        }
};
service.upload1(file1, str, stringMap, callback);
```

И после чего прописываете отмену запроса как то так(надо подправить):

```
if (condition && callback != null) {
callback.cancel();
}
```